# Is it possible to adjust sensitivity to start dragging/selecting on Magic Trackpad 2?

Tags: macos, big-sur, trackpad, magic-trackpad

I am forever accidentally selecting half my screen when moving the cursor using my Magic TrackPad 2... suddenly the entire webpage is selected because I did something accidentally. I *think* I might be doing a press instead of a touch but I'm not sure there isn't some other gesture, like I'm touching with a second finger or something accidentally - I can't reproduce it deliberately in a way which seems I could be doing it accidentally.

Are there any sensitivity settings or other controls that might help, or some obvious thing I am doing wrong I can correct?